# Highlight item into ControlTemplate using item's property 

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have a user control bound to appropriate ViewModel. I have a GraphLayout (using [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/)) on this control bound to ViewModel.Graph property:

```
<graph:ProductGraphLayout Graph="{Binding Path=Graph}" />
```

A number of VertexControl containing ProductVertex are placed on this layout. Content is represented by DataTemplate and theming applied using Style:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="VertexTemplate" DataType="{x:Type graph:ProductVertex}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=OneWay}" />
</DataTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type graphsharp:VertexControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type graphsharp:VertexControl}">
                <Border>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6695C4" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Vertex}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource VertexTemplate}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I change a style of the container (VertexControl) based on ProductVertex properties, say IsCurrent?

Comment: does a DataTrigger work in your case?

Comment: @blindmeis: Honestly I'm new to WPF and definitely weak in XAML so really not sure where to place DataTrigger and how to setup it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I've managed by myself how to achieve that:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="VertexTemplate" DataType="{x:Type graph:ProductSubstitutionVertex}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=OneWay}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCurrent}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EDF2F6" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: @blindmeis: Right! I've figured out how to place and bind it properly :)

Comment: @blindmeis: Need to wait 2 days more (local rules, I don't know) before I will be able to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the data structure you can use the `ProductVertex` object withing the `ControlTemplate` of the `VertexControl`. You could now e.g. use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to change the color of the border depending on the vertex object.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type graphsharp:VertexControl}">
    <Border>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{TemplateBinding Vertex.IsCurrent, Converter={StaticResource YourBoolToColorConverter}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Vertex}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource VertexTemplate}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```